# No detecta cambios en input añadido

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero añadir un input file con jquery, y que luego detecte si se selecciona algún fichero.
Pero solo se detecta si el input ya está creado de antes

Es un poco difícil de explicar, supongo que lo entenderán mejor con un ejemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/28nws20n/

¿A que se debe que los input que se añaden, no los detecte luego?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecutas el `append` crea elementos que no son reconocidos por el DOM, estos elementos son creados de manera **live** por así decirlo. Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es llamar al elemento `document` para que detecte todo nuevamente y pueda hacer funcionar tu elemento que se creo dinámicamente.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function(){
   alert("DETECT FILE");
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cig, sabía que era algo de este estilo pero no lo tenía muy claro. Ahora ya entiendo todo